# Associating Work Items with Pull Requests sets state to Done - Can I change that?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, when creating a Pull Request, it's possible to associate work items (Product Backlog Items, Bugs, Tasks, etc). When this happens, the state of the work item is automatically set to Done.

Is that configurable? We would like to associate work items and have them NOT change state.

I've looked through the Project Configuration, Team Configuration, and the Process Configuration and there appears to be no setting relevant to this action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that the work items will not be changed to Done state you can uncheck the checkbox when you complete the PR:

[image]

If you want that the work items will be changed to another state, is not possible yet, this is not configurable, there is an open [Feature Request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365704/customize-work-item-state-after-pr-is-closed.html) about it, you can upvote it.

**Edit: Microsoft added this feature in Sprint 174 with a preview access:**

> Starting in sprint 174, we have a new feature that allows you to set
> the work items to the desired state when the pull request is merged
> and completed. To do this, we scan the pull request description and
> look for the state value followed by the #mention of the work item(s).
> In this example, we are setting two user stories to Resolved and
> closing two tasks.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/new-in-azure-boards-sprint-174/

Comment: What Microsoft delivered in sprint 174 was not what the community asked for (we asked for process-level configuration of the target work item state, they added a possibility to customize the target state manually in every single PR). There is [a new feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1200823/ability-to-configure-target-work-item-state-after.html) covering the original requirements.